# Why does \nobreakdash inside a figure caption break unless previously used?

Tags: captions, amsmath

Simply put, the following does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{
        poly\nobreakdash-Si
    }
\end{figure}

poly\nobreakdash-Si % move this to before figure caption and it works

\end{document}
```

but, as noted in the code comment, if the command has been used in the body of the document before its use inside the figure caption it does compile (and produce the desired result, in a more complicated example).

Why does this happen?

The error message is `! Argument of \@tempb has an extra }.` I have tested this with pdflatex and lualatex in TeX Live 2017 and 2020.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  `\nobreakdash` needs to be "protected" in a moving argument: `\caption{poly\protect\nobreakdash-Si}`.  It's possible to define `\nobreakdash` in a way that doesn't require this, but the definition is an old one and hasn't been upgraded.

Comment: Thank you for quickly pointing me in the right direction. I've found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands and will be reading and pondering for a while.

Comment: Basically it fails in both cases. But in the one the failure doesn't give an error as \@tempa more or less by chance has a definition that avoids this.

Answer (score 1):

latex includes a better version of the `amsmath` command `\nobreakdash`, `\nobreakdashes`. It works with `--` and `---` and importantly here, it is robust so works in the section heading.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{
        poly\nobreakdashes-Si
    }
\end{figure}

poly\nobreakdashes-Si % move this to before figure caption and it works

\end{document}
```

Comment: So please fix `amsmath`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I only just noticed:-) The latex version was added in 2004, before the team picked up amsmath, documented as `This idea is borrowed from the \textsf{amsmath} package but here we define a robust command`

Comment: Fair enough.  Maybe just make `\nobreakdash` robust in `amsmath`.  Removing it could make existing documents unprocessable; not a good idea.